# What are the key constant values in Pygame.key.get_pressed()?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm learning Pygame from [thepythongamebook, and in the second example](http://thepythongamebook.com/en:pygame:step009) of code the following appear ( edited, since CURSORKEYS is defined in a class):

```
CURSORKEYS = slice(273,277)
...
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()[CURSORKEYS]
```

In the [Pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) it explains that `key.get_pressed()`:

> Returns a sequence of boolean values representing the state of every
>   key on the keyboard. Use the key constant values to index the array.

But I can't find a key constant index that makes sense here.

What keys (and from what key constant index) do the indices 273-276 appear in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pygame 

print(pygame.K_UP)    # 273
print(pygame.K_DOWN)  # 274
print(pygame.K_RIGHT) # 275
print(pygame.K_LEFT)  # 276
```

Other key constants (without values) are on page https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

But you can always use constants so you don't need values.